# What is git log date?

Tags: git, merge, logging

What does the date in the description of each commit of 'git log' mean? Is it the date commit was initially done on some repository or is it the date it was merged to current repository?

Answer (score 5):

It is the date of the original commit. More precisely, the *author* commit date, which can be different than the real commit date, for example when a commit is cherry-picked or rebased: the original commit date is kept as *author date*, and the time it is picked is the commit date.

Pulling from a remote repository preserves both commit date and author dates.

Comment: So if commits in 'git log' do not follow the date order, that means they were pulled separately. Is that right?

Comment: See my edit for clarification; typically you see different ordering because ordering happens by commit date, while you see author dates in the log. It has nothing to do with different pulls.